# a complex analysis problem about entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I don't know how to find a bound for $f(z)$. Can you give me some ideas? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1. Restrict $f$ to the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$. Call this function $g:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Now, using Schwarz Reflection principle extend $g$ to an entire function $\widetilde{g}$ on $\mathbb{C}$.
2. Compare $\widetilde{g}$ and $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ using the identity theorem.
3. Apply Liouville's theorem to $\widetilde{g}$.

Comment: You don't need Schwarz reflection. Because f is real on the real axis, f satisfies $f(\overline z) = \overline {f(z)}.$

Comment: @zhm From what theorem? I am a bit rusty on Complex analysis at the moment and don't see how you see it directly

Comment: If $f$ is real on the real axis, then it's Taylor coefficients are all real. The result follows easily.